How can I solve the Mongodb atlas connection error in nodejs?
I'm getting below error while try to connect mongodb atlas database with nodejs mongoose:
Error: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted.
Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
Mongodb URL: mongodb+srv://username:password@expressmongocrud.godpihs.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=ExpressMongoCrud
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import config from 'config';
import log from "./logger";

async function dbConnection() {
    const dbUrl = config.get<string>("dbUrl");

    try {
        log.info("Connecting to database...");
        const connection = await mongoose.connect(dbUrl);
        log.info("Database Connected");
    } catch (e: any) {
        log.error("Database connection error");
        log.fatal(e.message);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

export default dbConnection;

I tried to connect the above URL in MongoDBCompass and it is successfully connected.
I also set my current IP address and 0.0.0.0/0 in atlas Network Access but still getting the same error.

Do you have a network firewall or proxy server which may block the connection?

Try an older version of mongoose, I remember there was a bug in the latest version.

This question is similar to: Error : "Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It was issue with mongoose version 8.8.4. I downgrade the mongoose version to 7.8.2 and it's working.

Now, it's solved. It was issue with mongoose version.
Before:
"@typegoose/typegoose": "^12.9.1",
"mongoose": "^8.8.4"

Changed with:
"@typegoose/typegoose": "^11.8.1",
"mongoose": "^7.8.2"

