Not able to establish connection to Mongodb in NestJS when using MongooseModule.forRoot()
Not able to establish connection to Mongodb in NestJS Application when using MongooseModule.forRoot() method. It works fine when tested Connection with mongoose script and mongosh or using MongoDb Studio. Issue is specific when using MongooseModule.forRoot in NestJS application. It gives following error:
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist
All the concerned IPs are added in the whitelist (so that should not be the issue).

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79299039/how-can-i-solve-the-mongodb-atlas-connection-error-in-nodejs

@ray yes I have checked that thread and added Allow access form any IP to the Network Access in MongoDb Atlas but still getting same error.

@Vidip Please check my answer under the link. That involves a mitigation of downgrading mongoose version.

Thanks @ray ! yes it worked by downgrading the mongoose version.

@Vidip Glad that it helped. Consider closing this post as duplicate so this post can serve as a signpost to the solution.
