App deployed to fly.io can't connect to mongoDB cloud atlas, works fine locally
I am deploying a small app using a mongodb database to fly.io. I have verified that it works locally.
I have veried that the connection string is correct through flyctl logs and I have whitelisted 0.0.0.0/0 on mongodb cloud atlas.
I get the following error in flyctl logs
2024-12-21T15:08:47Z app[d8dd1e4f4641e8] arn [info]connecting to mongodb+srv://${username}:${password}@cluster0.cah2bcd.mongodb.net/phoneBookApp?retryWrites=true&ssl=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0
2024-12-21T15:08:47Z app[d8dd1e4f4641e8] arn [info]Server running on port 8080
2024-12-21T15:09:00Z health[d8dd1e4f4641e8] arn [info]Health check on port 8080 is now passing.
2024-12-21T15:09:17Z app[d8dd1e4f4641e8] arn [info]error connecting to MongoDB: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79299039/how-can-i-solve-the-mongodb-atlas-connection-error-in-nodejs
